# Can use MVVM Light Toolkit to build a profitable commercial software?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I doubt whether I can use MVVM Light Toolkit to build a profitable commercial software? whether need to be authorized?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Um, perhaps try reading the license? https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/license

Comment: I have read. But I still don't know I need to do sth?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: @JMK I dont ensure I understand this license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVVM Light Toolkit is a very strong lightweight framework which can of course helps you to build profitable commercial applications.

From the legal point it runs under the MIT License which you can see here and hopefully find the answers to your questions:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/license

In case I did understand your question wrong please feel free to comment.
HTH

Comment: In the license, it said "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.". But whether my company need to be authorized?

Comment: Get in touch with the main contributor and driver at http://galasoft.ch/ he will help u surely with all questions